# color changing button onclick

Tags: javascript, button

Okay so so far I have this page with a few buttons in it, whenever you click the button it turns red now i want to add that whenever you click it  more times the color changes.

so for example: first the button is green, on the first click it turns red, on the third click it turns pink and so on.

I tried to do this with the set_onclick function I made and then multiple this code:

```
for (var a = 1; a < (amount + 1); a++) {
    document.getElementById("button" + a).setAttribute("onclick", "onbuttonclicked(" + a + ")");
```

but i dont get it to work

```js
page();
    
function onbuttonclicked(a) {
  document.getElementById("button" + a).classList.remove("button")
  document.getElementById("button" + a).classList.add("clickedbutton")
}

function set_onclick(amount) {
  for (var a = 1; a < (amount + 1); a++) {
    document.getElementById("button" + a).setAttribute("onclick", "onbuttonclicked(" + a + ")");
  }
}
    
function page() {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "grey";
  //style page
    
  createButtons(30);
}
    
    
function createButtons(amount){
  for (var a = 1;a <(amount + 1); a++) {
           
     var button = document.createElement("button"); 
     button.classList.add("button")
     button.id = "button" + a; 
     button.innerHTML = "button " + a; 
     container.appendChild(button);
  }
  set_onclick(amount);
}
```

```css
body{
    background-color: white;
}

#container{
    top: 10px;
    padding: 82px;
    margin: auto;
    width: 800px;
    height: 350px;
    background-color: grey;
    position: relative;
}

#buttons{
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

button{
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 30px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 140px;
    height: 50px;
}

body{
    background-color: white;
}

#container{
    top: 10px;
    padding: 82px;
    margin: auto;
    width: 800px;
    height: 350px;
    background-color: grey;
    position: relative;
}

#buttons{
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

button{
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 30px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 140px;
    height: 50px;
}

.clickedbutton {
    background-color: red;
}
    
.button {
   background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>buttons</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="buttons.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container"></div>
        <script src="buttons.js"></script>
     </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said the color of the `button` is dependent on how many times you clicked the button, and you will have to manage a local state for each button since there are many buttons

I think the the first thing you need is an object that will change the color like this, where the key is `count` and value is color

```
const obj = {
1 : "red",
2 : "blue"
3 : "pink"
4 : "skyblue"
...
...
...
}
```

and then change the color according to it

```js
var colorMap = {
  1 : "red",
  2 : "blue",
  3 : "pink",
  4 : "hotpink",
  5 : "brown",
  6 : "yellow",
  7 : "black"
}



page();
    
function page() {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "grey";
  createButtons(30);
  

}

document.body.addEventListener("click", (e)=>{
    if(e.target.classList.contains("button")){
     let currentbtnCount = parseInt(e.target.getAttribute("data-current-count")) + 1;
     e.target.style.backgroundColor = colorMap[currentbtnCount] ? colorMap[currentbtnCount] : "black";
     e.target.setAttribute("data-current-count", currentbtnCount);
    }
   })
    
    
function createButtons(amount){
  for (var a = 1;a <(amount + 1); a++) {
     var button = document.createElement("button"); 
     button.classList.add("button")
     button.setAttribute("data-current-count", "0")
     button.id = "button" + a; 
     button.innerHTML = "button " + a; 
     container.appendChild(button);
  }
}
```

```css
body{
    background-color: white;
}

#container{
    top: 10px;
    padding: 82px;
    margin: auto;
    width: 800px;
    height: 350px;
    background-color: grey;
    position: relative;
}

#buttons{
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

button{
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 30px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 140px;
    height: 50px;
}

body{
    background-color: white;
}

#container{
    top: 10px;
    padding: 82px;
    margin: auto;
    width: 800px;
    height: 350px;
    background-color: grey;
    position: relative;
}

#buttons{
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

button{
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 30px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 140px;
    height: 50px;
}

.clickedbutton {
    background-color: red;
}
    
.button {
   background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>buttons</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="buttons.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container"></div>
        <script src="buttons.js"></script>
     </body>
</html>
```

#### And if you want complete random colors then here is another one

```js
function random_rgba() {
    var o = Math.round, r = Math.random, s = 255;
    return 'rgba(' + o(r()*s) + ',' + o(r()*s) + ',' + o(r()*s) + ',' + r().toFixed(1) + ')';
}


page();
    
function page() {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "grey";
  createButtons(30);
  

}

document.body.addEventListener("click", (e)=>{
    if(e.target.classList.contains("button")){
     e.target.style.backgroundColor = random_rgba();
    }
   })
    
    
function createButtons(amount){
  for (var a = 1;a <(amount + 1); a++) {
     var button = document.createElement("button"); 
     button.classList.add("button")
     button.setAttribute("data-current-count", "0")
     button.id = "button" + a; 
     button.innerHTML = "button " + a; 
     container.appendChild(button);
  }
}
```

```css
body{
    background-color: white;
}

#container{
    top: 10px;
    padding: 82px;
    margin: auto;
    width: 800px;
    height: 350px;
    background-color: grey;
    position: relative;
}

#buttons{
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

button{
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 30px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 140px;
    height: 50px;
}

body{
    background-color: white;
}

#container{
    top: 10px;
    padding: 82px;
    margin: auto;
    width: 800px;
    height: 350px;
    background-color: grey;
    position: relative;
}

#buttons{
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

button{
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 30px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 140px;
    height: 50px;
}

.clickedbutton {
    background-color: red;
}
    
.button {
   background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>buttons</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="buttons.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container"></div>
        <script src="buttons.js"></script>
     </body>
</html>
```

Comment: with this kind of code is it also possible to hide the button after certain clicks? or i need to make an other code for that

Answer (score 0):

Make a function that will count clicks and change the color of the button depending on the amount of the clicks.

You can just change a class like this:

```
document.querySelector(".MyElement").className = "MyClass";
```

hope You know that when searching for a class with querySelector You need to use '.' in front of the name of the class. If You try to find by ID either use querySelector with '#' in front of an ID or use getElementById:

```
document.getElementById("MyElement").className = "MyClass";
```

Example:

```
let counter = 0 

document.getElemenetById('button').onclick = function(){
    counter += 1
}

if (counter = 0) {
    document.getElementById('button').className = 'red'
} else if (counter = 1) {
    document.getElementById('button').className = 'blue'
}
```

or

```
let counter = 0 

document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", counter += 1);

if (counter = 0) {
    document.getElementById('button').className = 'red'
} else if (counter = 1) {
    document.getElementById('button').className = 'blue'
}
```

or

```
let counter = 0 
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

<script>
    function myFunction() {
        counter += 1
    }

   if (counter = 0) {
        document.getElementById('button').className = 'red'
   } else if (counter = 1) {
        document.getElementById('button').className = 'blue'
   }
</script>
```

Comment: i made an var ''count=0;'' and a function with ''button.onclick= count+1' but I dont get how to change the colors

Comment: I get that i need to make a function that will count the clicks but i dont get how to put in the function that it changes colors